# How do I correctly set up this validation in my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

When I validate the format of a string, I'll do:

```
validates :link, :uniqueness => true,
               :format => { :with => (regular expression) }
```

I want the link to be either a youtube video by this regex:

`/^http:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)/`

or a vimeo video:

`/^http:\/\/www\.vimeo\.com\/(\d+)/`

How do I set up this validation in my model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could combine those two regular expressions into one, though I presume you mean you have two different expressions instead of two identical ones:

```
validates :link,
  :uniqueness => true,
  :format => {
    :with => %r[http://(?:www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=(\w+)|www\.vimeo\.com...)]
  }
```

Using `%r[...]` instead of `/.../` saves you from having to escape all the slashes.

Also note that YouTube may use a `youtu.be` domain, so you may need yet another part to your regular expression. If this thing gets totally out of hand you may want to take a different approach and have a list of regexps you compare it against:

```
VALID_URLS = [
  %r[http://www\.youtube\.com/watch\?v=(\w+)],
  %r[http://www\.youtu\.be/(\w+)],
  %r[ ... ]
]
```

Then validate something like this:

```
validates :link,
  :uniqueness => true,
  :format => {
    :with => Regexp.new(VALID_URLS.join('|'))
  }
```

Comment: can youtube videos also have different parameters besides `v`?

Comment: I think `v` is pretty standard, but you'd have to experiment to be sure. Apart from the shortener, and other random arguments, that's what I expect.